# How to remove <script> tag if the device is mobile ? M1

Tags: javascript, script

I am trying to remove certain dynamic script tags if the device is mobile. I have something like this to start with:

Vendor/MobileDetect/Helper/Data.php :

```
<?php

class Vendor_MobileDetect_Helper_Data
{
    public function isMobile() {
        $isMobile = Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match(
            Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
            $_SERVER
        );
        return $isMobile;
    }
}
```

app/design/frontend/rwd/company/layout/local.xml :

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>nwdthemes/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js</name><url helper="vendor_mobiledetect/isMobile"/></action>
</reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

The problem is that the function is removing the script tag for all devices (desktop, tablet, mobile). I just want it removed for mobile.

Thanks for any help!